# Why 10.0.64.0/24 overlaps with 10.0.66.0/18?

Tags: networking, ip, cidr

Why 10.0.64.0/24 overlaps with 10.0.66.0/18? I thought that 10.0.64.0/24 will go up to 10.0.64.255.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `10.0.66.0/18` network range is `10.0.64.0` - `10.0.127.255`, which includes the entire `10.0.64.0/24` network:

```
> ipcalc 10.0.66.0/18
Address:   10.0.66.0            00001010.00000000.01 000010.00000000
Netmask:   255.255.192.0 = 18   11111111.11111111.11 000000.00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.63.255           00000000.00000000.00 111111.11111111
=>
Network:   10.0.64.0/18         00001010.00000000.01 000000.00000000
HostMin:   10.0.64.1            00001010.00000000.01 000000.00000001
HostMax:   10.0.127.254         00001010.00000000.01 111111.11111110
Broadcast: 10.0.127.255         00001010.00000000.01 111111.11111111
Hosts/Net: 16382                 Class A, Private Internet
```

Answer (score 2):

They overlap in that 10.0.64.1 is in both 10.0.64.0/24 and 10.0.66.0/18, for example.

It's not the /24 range which is causing you a problem - it's the /18 range, which will include everything from 10.0.64.0 to 10.0.127.255.

The "66" in 10.0.66.0/18 is pretty weird, to be honest... if only the top 18 bits are relevant, why is the 23rd bit being set?